# Can i hide .laccdb files or change its name with MS Access settings

Tags: ms-access-2010, settings, user-experience

Title says it simply.

I have a MS Access Database on a shared drive and the majority of users aren't experts so quite often the leave their PC with the Database open then it locks the PC, someone else will come along and switch it to their account, go to open the Database and get confused by the two files with the same name.

I can think of solutions for this e.g. using shortcuts so they dont actually see the laccdb or accdb file

But what I want to know is if there are any settings in Access (2010) that can make the .laccdb file hidden when it is created or just give it a random name like word or excel tmp files?

When I google this the results are more for removing people from the database so you can delete the laccdb file

Comment: I believe the answer is simply no. Multiple users on same computer? This is a multi-user database? Sounds like db is not split design.

Comment: It is split if you mean has a front end(for UI) and a back end(for Data) The front end does have a USys table for the Ribbon though

Comment: So the frontend and backend are in same folder? Everyone runs the same frontend file? Each user should run their own copy of frontend.

Comment: The backend is in a folder that the users dont have access to and the frontend is on a shared drive and they all use that front end

Comment: Each user can set up a desktop shortcut to the frontend and then they won't have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a multi-user setup even though just one user can be active.

So you need to distribute the frontend to each user while having the backend in a folder with access for all users - that could be a subfolder of C:\Users\Public.

Here's is a script that will handle the distribution:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)